# C# Incremental Source Generator not outputing anything

Tags: c#, code-generation, sourcegenerators

i am trying to make a Source Generator and up until the file generation everything seems to work fine.

When i attach a debugger i see it go trough the node filter and i am getting results as expected. But when i try to generate the code nothing seems to happen. While debugging it goes trough the GenerateCode method but there is no error nor exceptions. Here is the relevant code :

```
[Generator]
public class CustomGenerator : IIncrementalGenerator
{
    public void Initialize(IncrementalGeneratorInitializationContext context)
    {
#if DEBUG
        if (!Debugger.IsAttached)
        {
            Debugger.Launch();
            SpinWait.SpinUntil(() => Debugger.IsAttached, 5000);
        }
#endif

        var attributes = context.SyntaxProvider.CreateSyntaxProvider(IsKnownAttribute, Static.GetDbAttributeOrNull).Where(t => t is not null).Collect();
#pragma warning disable CS8622 // Nullability of reference types in type of parameter doesn't match the target delegate (possibly because of nullability attributes).
        context.RegisterSourceOutput(attributes, GenerateCode);
#pragma warning restore CS8622 // Nullability of reference types in type of parameter doesn't match the target delegate (possibly because of nullability attributes).
    }

    private static bool IsKnownAttribute(SyntaxNode syntaxNode, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        if (syntaxNode is not AttributeSyntax attribute)
        {
            return false;
        }

        var className = nameof(DbGenerationAttribute).Replace("Attribute", "");
        return attribute.Name.ToString().Equals(className, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
            || attribute.Name.ToFullString().Equals(className, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase); ;
    }

    private static void GenerateCode(SourceProductionContext context, ImmutableArray<DbConnectionInfo> items)
    {
        context.AddSource("TestGen.g.cs", @"
namespace AtuomationDemo.SourceGeneration.Generated
{
    public class MyClass
    {
        public static void PrintHello(string name)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine($""Hello { name }!"");
        }
    }
}");
    }
}
```

I tried adding the generator's attribute inside a .Net6 App (Rest API), but i kept getting a warning that an instance of the generator could not be found/created.
I then moved it to a NetStandard2.0 class library but i am still not getting anything.

I tried looking for the generated files and found nothing. Also tried using the class that should have been generated but nothing came out of it.

Am i doing something wrong here?

Comment: Did you figure this out? I've been trying to build even a hello world source generator but I'm having no luck. No methods are called at all.

Comment: @NibblyPig you can try out [mine](https://github.com/gurustron/default-record-ctor) for example =)